# My WiFi (with my own password) is connected to our office network. Is it secure?

Tags: network, wifi

Is there a possibility that they can see my browsing history, media transfers, Skype sessions and even FaceTime?

Comment: They can see whatever traffic you pass through their routers.

Comment: Please try to specify the network encryption type (WEP, WPA, etc.) and the exact services you are interested in. Do I understand correctly that you try to protect your data from your employer?

Comment: On behalf of all network admins, I have to ask that you please do NOT attach your own WIFI AP to your office network. You are exposing your company to untold risks.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your IT staff are oblivious enough to allow to install your own WiFi access point, it's safe to assume they're not conducting advanced network analysis to figure out patterns in your encrypted Skype sessions or extract secrets from your HTTPS sessions.

Please note that the traffic is coming out of your laptop into the WiFi access point which is connected **to your Office's router** and then to the internet. The inbound traffic is coming from the Internet **to your Office's router** which will pass it to your access point and finally to your laptop. Whatever you're browsing or doing online can be logged and observed by their router.

Luckily for you, FaceTime and Skype encrypt their traffic. As for your other "media transfer" activities, if they're not over HTTPS then assume your employer knows about them and act accordingly.